Jenkins on K8S - Kubernetes secrets as build step env vars
After too much searching, I'm still not sure how we can use K8S secrets as env vars in our declarative Jenkins pipelines. We've tried a few different approaches, including the following. The build involves setting up a Python container that pushes Python wheels to our private ECR registry.
build_pod_config = '''
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  namespace: "jenkins"
spec:
  containers:
    # ...
    - name: 'python'
      image: '870326185936.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/605data/build-tools-python:3.12'
      command:
        - 'sleep'
      args:
        - 'infinity'
      env:  
        - name: PYPI_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: 'secret-credentials'
              key: 'pypi-admin-pwd'
   # ... 

  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
    runAsGroup: 1000
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: "dev-jenkins"
  volumes:
   # ...
'''
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml build_pod_config
      defaultContainer 'python'
    }
  }  // agent

  stages {
    stage("Setup") {
      steps {
        script {
          // we don't clone here, the job definition handles everything
          this_branch = "${GIT_BRANCH}".trim()
          echo "Building branch ${this_branch}..."
          currentBuild.displayName = "${this_branch}"
          push_branches = [
              "origin/master"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    // ...

    stage("Publish") {
      when {
        expression { push_branches.contains(this_branch) }
      }
      steps {
        echo "Pushing wheel and Docker image"
        container("python") {
          echo "Pushing wheel, src distributions to PyPi"
          // From the Kubernetes plugin, but currently not working
          secretEnvVar(key: 'PYPI_PWD', secretName: 'secret-credentials', secretKey: 'pypi-pwd', optional: false) {
            // sh("""python -m pip install '.[publish]'""")
            sh("""python -m twine upload --repository-url https://pypi.shared-services.605.nu dist/* --user admin --password ${PYPI_PWD}""")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    // ...
  }
}


The issue is that while the K8S secret value above appears as an environment variable in the Python container, it is NOT available from within our pipeline step that pushes the wheel to our registry.  We would like to use such K8S secret values as env vars in our pipelines.
We've tried everything we can think of or find on the net with no luck.  The Jenkins Kubernetes plugin does define "secretEnvVar", but it appears to be available only in scripted pipelines, not declarative ones. Any ideas on how to set the K8S secret-based env vars in our build steps?
We'd like to keep using the declarative approach with a YAML build pod configuration because we have some tooling to help users create such pipelines.  We'd also prefer not to involve Jenkins credentials if possible.
Any ideas?

I have a feeling that it actually works but not in a way you would expect. Depending on the pipeline type, Jenkins can change the name of the environment variable if it's defined twice. Even declarative Pipeline and declarative Multibranch Pipeline work differently in this regard.
To make sure, you can check it by running printenv in your container. The values will likely be masked, but chances are that you'll see something like this:
...
PYPI_PWD=*****
pypi_pwd=*****
...

Regardless of that, I'm not sure that you even need that environment variable to be extracted with secretEnvVar - moreover, if I recall (and read the docs) correctly, it doesn't even work like that and is intended to construct a pod template when you don't have a YAML file. And this way of defining a pod template is deprecated in favor of YAML, AFAIR.
So, given that, and the fact that twine upload is able to utilize the environment variables itself, I would try to
simply define the standard TWINE_PASSWORD environment variable in the pod template instead of a custom PYPI_PWD. This is also safer as you don't use the Groovy string interpolation that makes the secrets used on CLI available in plain text:
build_pod_config = '''
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  namespace: "jenkins"
spec:
  containers:
    # ...
    - name: 'python'
      image: '870326185936.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/605data/build-tools-python:3.12'
      command:
        - 'sleep'
      args:
        - 'infinity'
      env:  
        - name: TWINE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: 'secret-credentials'
              key: 'pypi-admin-pwd'
   # ... 
'''
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml build_pod_config
      defaultContainer 'python'
    }
  }  // agent

  stages {
    // I omitted the unrelated parts for brevity 
    // ...

    stage("Publish") {
      when {
        expression { push_branches.contains(this_branch) }
      }
      steps {
        echo "Pushing wheel and Docker image"
        container("python") {
          echo "Pushing wheel, src distributions to PyPi"
          sh 'python -m twine upload --repository-url https://pypi.shared-services.605.nu dist/* --user admin'         
        }
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    // ...
  }
}

You can set the other options like TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL and TWINE_USERNAME the same way, so your pod templates could be shared and ready-to-use with any pipeline, and the pipelines are simpler. If you don't want to include them in the pod template, you can still define them within the environment declarative block per Jenkinsfile:
environment {
  TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL = 'https://pypi.shared-services.605.nu'
  TWINE_USERNAME = 'admin'
}

Side note: you can use label argument of sh step to avoid the cluttering echo steps. Jenkins will automatically prepend the command log with this text in the build log:
sh script: 'python -m twine upload dist/*',
  label: 'Pushing wheel, src distributions to PyPi'


Thanks for the reply, Alexander.  I'm seeking an answer to the question of why I can't seem to pull in K8S secrets that appear as container env vars (which works fine using YAML) into declarative pipeline build steps, where only a few Jenkins-populated env vars are available.

@JonathanC It's not designed for this. The documentation for the K8s plugin that I referred to in my answer does not even mention this capability - it can only create a pod/container template, where the secrets will be available as environment variables. If you use YAML templates, secretEnvVar doesn't make sense. You might want to look into the Kubernetes Credentials plugin (that has little to no documentation, though, and we didn't get it working in our org, unfortunately - AFAIR it doesn't support multiple clusters or smth like that).

I did notice the lack of documentation!  I also tried creating a new Jenkins library function in Groovy that uses the SecretEnvVar class directly, but it doesn't seem to work either.  I probably missed something.  In any event, I'll see if there's a better option available via another plugin.
